# Python Pandas - Add records where header matches csv

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I've got a python script using Pandas to export JSON data to CSV.
Recently the data online had changed and I didn't realize it and the new records do not match up in line with the headers.

Is it possible to get Pandas to check the header and update the records in the correct format to CSV?
Or would you be able to suggest a better way to do this?

Thanks to all!

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

I see :

```
df = pd.read_json("your_json_file.json") # load your json data

required_columns = ["col1", "col2", "col3"]  # replace with your actual column headers

for col in required_columns:
    if col not in df.columns:
        df[col] = None # or replace with some default value
```